# How to display a hyperlink in hudson/jenkins build output console

Tags: jenkins, hudson, jenkins-plugins, hudson-plugins, automated-deploy

How do I display a hyperlink (weblink) in [hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/)/[jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) build output console?

What I'm trying to achieve is, during a hudson/jenkins build based on certain condition, I would like to display a hyperlink.
When a user click on that link, it should open a new browser window and show the page.

Is there a plugin to do this? Any suggestions please?

Comment: forgot to mention, would like to dynamically construct the url context based on the condition

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you enter, for example:

```
echo 'http://example.com'
```

in a **Build** step *Execute shell → Command* the address will be hyperlinked in the *Console Output*, though not with `target="_blank"`. But middle-clicking on it opens it in a new tab or window – depending on your browser preferences.

Comment: Thanks that helped. Is it possible to have href. 
e.g
Text would show "click here" but underline endpoint would be an actual URL.

Just dont want to show full URL. ...I"m trying but not able to get it :)

Comment: @enthuguy Unfortunately it isn't. `<a href="...">...</a>` is printed as plain text with just the content of `href` hyperlinked. And, BTW, „_click here_“ isn't a good link text anyway. The text should cover _what_ can be expected to be found when following the link, not _how_ to follow it. The latter is known by any browser user anyway. And it's not just clicking: it can be tapping with a stylus or just a finger or tabbing to it and hitting <Enter>.

Answer (score 13):

When using a (system) groovy script or Jenkins job pipeline (without sandbox) you may want to try e.g.:

```
import hudson.console.ModelHyperlinkNote
println hudson.console.ModelHyperlinkNote.encodeTo('http://example.com', 'example')
```

Please find the full API of `hudson.console.ModelHyperlinkNote` here:
http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/console/ModelHyperlinkNote.html

Comment: That's it! Solved the problem I had -- esp. worth noting it has special handling for `Job`, `Build`, `User` and `Node`, in addition to general purpose method mentioned here.